# Conversion of UTF-8 encoded IStream to string

Tags: delphi

I have an IStream interface which contains UTF-8 encoded text. I want to convert this to a string. I use the following code:

```
uses
  System.Classes,
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  Vcl.Axctrls;

Function StreamToString(Stream : IStream; var S : String) : Boolean;
{ Saves an UTF-8 encoded IStream to the string S
  Result = True if ok }
var
  OLEStream : TOLEStream;
  StringStream : TStringStream;
begin
  S := '';
  Result := True;

  OLEStream := TOLEStream.Create(Stream);
  StringStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    try
      StringStream.LoadFromStream(OLEStream);
      S := UTF8ToString(RawByteString(StringStream.DataString));
    except
      S := '';
      Result := False;
    end;
  finally
    StringStream.Free;
    OLEStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This works in my tests. But I am not sure if this is a really robust solution that works in all cases?

Comment: You'd normally read into a byte array, and use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString()`. I'd avoid `TStringStream` where possible, it always seems to do more harm than good in my experience. I think your exception handling is pretty odd. I can't understand why you'd suppress exceptions. Just let them propagate and have somebody who knows how to deal with them, deal with them. Protecting two resources with a single try/finally is wrong. But that problem will disappear once you ditch the string stream!

Comment: You code does several copies. Not very efficient. IStream has a CopyTo method which you can use to copy data to a buffer for direct conversion.

Comment: @fpiette Yes you can call the `IStream` methods directly, but it's a pretty revolting experience. I think `TOLEStream` is a good option here.

Comment: I'ved use the TStreamAdapter to interface with iStream, it works well. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStreamAdapter

Comment: It would be simpler to read the `IStream` data directly into a `UTF8String` and then assign that as-is to the dest `String` and let the RTL handle the conversions. Or, like David said, read into a `Byte` array and then use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString()`. If you do use `TStringStream`, there is no need to use `UTF8ToString()`, just create the `TStringStream` with `TEncoding.UTF8` specified, then copy the `IStream` data into it, and then assign its `DataString` as-is to the dest `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments by David Heffernan and Remy Lebeau I changed the code to:

```
Function StreamToString(Stream : IStream) : string;
{ Returns a string from an UTF-8 encoded IStream }
var
  OLEStream : TOLEStream;
  Buffer : TBytes;
begin
  Result := '';

  OLEStream := TOLEStream.Create(Stream);
  try
    SetLength(Buffer, OLEStream.Size);
    OLEStream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    if OLEStream.Read(Buffer[0], Length(Buffer)) <> OLEStream.Size
      then raise Exception.Create('A problem occured: The stream could not be read');
    Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer);
  finally
    OLEStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```